Azure DevOps built react native new arch for IOS failed when pod install
I already have an React Native project before and already setup CI/CD for it by using Azure DevOps. But now when I upgraded to new arch 0.76, it failed when pod install.
My script for pod install:
(I already have a script for bundle install inside this file)
- script: |
      export RUBY_THREAD_VM_STACK_SIZE=1000000
      export RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1
      bundle exec pod install
    displayName: 'iOS | CocoaPods packages installing with new architecture'
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ios'
    condition: ne(variables['cache_pods_restored'], 'true')

And the error:
bundler: failed to load command: pod (/Users/runner/work/1/s/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/bin/pod)
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:230:in `loaded_spec'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:186:in `spec'


I could build the app on my Mac but couldn't built it on AzureDevOps.
Can you give me a hand?

activesupport 7.0.8.6
ruby 3.3.0
algoliasearch 1.27.5
cocoapods-core 1.14.3


Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Here are some troubleshoot suggestions: 1. You can try to use the code of the old arch version to test whether the same problem occurs.
2. Is the software version listed in the question the version on your local Mac? If your pipeline runs on a Microsoft hosted macOS agent, you can compare the versions here to see if they are different.


You can try to create a Self-hosted macOS agent on your local Mac and run the pipeline to see if the same problem occurs.

